# Printing goes to queue only

Tags: printing, canon

My 12.04 machine sees the printer, a Canon BJC-1000.  Print request of any kind including test pages will be sent to queue and kept there.  I can purge them but not make it print.  Is there a compatibility problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto Page preview
2. Select print from printer icon

After that It will be ok and you will can print again from the main Print option